# How to retrieve info on a loaded assembly at runtime? (c# , .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

In .NET c# 3.5 I have a console application (A) that references several assemblies(X, Y, Z).

How can I get the version information of the loaded assemblies at run time?

I can use reflection to get the info on the currently executing assembly like this

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString()
```

but not the loaded assemblies.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JP's answer will give you all of the assemblies in the AppDomain. If you only want the assemblies that your current assembly references directly, you can use:

```
var names = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
```

That will give you the names, including version information.

Comment: Does this account for binding redirects? I.e. does it show what's actually loaded or only what is referenced? Would that be a difference between JP Alioto's answer and this one?

Comment: @xr280xr: I believe it will show what's *referenced*, yes. If you need to depend on that behaviour though, I'd suggest you test it for yourself.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the [list of loaded assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies.aspx) from the AppDomain ...

```
var la = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

Comment: What he said.  AppDomain is fun at time.