# How does .NET resolve different versions of the same package?

Tags: nuget, .net-5, assembly-resolution

This question pertains to .NET 5+, not .NET Framework.

Consider the following dependency tree:

- `MyWebsite` has package references to `RandomWebLibrary` 1.0.0 and `RandomJsonLibrary` 2.0.0.
- The NuGet package `RandomWebLibrary` 1.0.0 has a package reference to `RandomJsonLibrary` 1.0.0.
- The NuGet package `RandomJsonLibrary` has no dependencies.

My questions:

1. What version(s) of `RandomJsonLibrary` will be loaded at runtime?
2. What happens if `RandomJsonLibrary` 2.0.0 has a completely different API than `RandomJsonLibrary` 1.0.0?
3. Can the author of `MyWebsite` do anything to fix problems that arise from having multiple versions of `RandomJsonLibrary` in the dependency tree? Is there an equivalent of .NET Framework's binding redirects in .NET 5+?

I'm asking out of curiosity, not because I am encountering a problem. For reference, here is the documentation on [Understanding AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/dependency-loading/understanding-assemblyloadcontext) which seems relevant but did not answer my question.

Comment: 1) you can [write some simple code to find out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866487/how-to-retrieve-info-on-a-loaded-assembly-at-runtime-c-net), 2) then something is going to break, 3) Why would MyWebsite have an explicit dependency on something that is already covered by a child package, which is in direct conflict with?

Comment: https://michaelscodingspot.com/assemblies-load-in-dotnet/

Comment: For example, in a simple description, this article may be helpful. [Assembly version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/versioning#assembly-version)

Comment: Does the [NuGet Dependency Resolution Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002999) help answer your questions? (e.g. `nearest-wins` rule)

Answer (score 4):

These questions are answered by the documentation page [How NuGet resolves package dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution).  The "Dependency resolution with PackageReference" section is what's relevant to this question since we are talking .NET 5+.

> When the package graph for an application contains different versions of the same package, **NuGet chooses the package that's closest to the application in the graph and ignores all others.** This behavior allows an application to override any particular package version in the dependency graph.
>
> In the example below, the application depends directly on Package B with a version constraint of >=2.0. The application also depends on Package A which in turn also depends on Package B, but with a >=1.0 constraint. Because the dependency on Package B 2.0 is nearer to the application in the graph, that version is used:

[image: Application using the Nearest Wins rule]

To answer the original questions:

1. `RandomJsonLibrary` 2.0.0 will be loaded at runtime.
2. I *believe* `RandomWebLibrary` will throw exceptions at runtime if `RandomJsonLibrary` 1.0.0 and 2.0.0 have incompatible APIs.
3. The author of `MyWebsite` can choose the exact version of any dependent package by installing that package directly into `MyWebsite`. In the case of `RandomJsonLibrary`, the author of `MyWebsite` should probably downgrade to `RandomJsonLibrary` 1.0.0 to prevent `RandomWebLibrary` from breaking. AFAIK there are no binding redirects in .NET 5+.

Comment: Thank you @martin-ullrich for pointing me to the appropriate documentation. Also, let me know if I got any of the specifics wrong in this answer.